# Do I need to recreate a new Socket everytime I need to send something to a server or receive something?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

In the example below, in the `while` loop,

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-make-a-socket-connection-to-a-server.html

In the client class, he keeps recreating the socket object. Is this approach correct ? Can't I reuse 1 socket ?

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class TestClientSocket {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        final String host = "localhost";
        final int portNumber = 81;
        System.out.println("Creating socket to '" + host + "' on port " + portNumber);

        while (true) {
            Socket socket = new Socket(host, portNumber); //THIS HERE ISN'T GOING TO BE SLOW ??
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

            System.out.println("server says:" + br.readLine());

            BufferedReader userInputBR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String userInput = userInputBR.readLine();

            out.println(userInput);

            System.out.println("server says:" + br.readLine());

            if ("exit".equalsIgnoreCase(userInput)) {
                socket.close();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please include the relevant code excerpt into your question?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin It is in the link I posted..

Comment: For each client connect to the `ServerSocket`, you must create a new `Socket` to facilitate the communications. Depending on your solution, you could maintain the `Socket` (ie don't close it), typically done in a separate thread

Comment: @MadProgrammer cool thanks man, I have added the code to. So which method is more efficient ?

Comment: @TrtTrt The is overhead occurred in establishing a `Socket` connection, which you use will depend on the context of the solution you're trying to solve, for example, you might only need to make a single request for data from the server, so what's the point of keeping the socket open? On the other hand, you might need to make repeated requests for data (or the server might send periodical updates), in which case, it's better to keep the `Socket` open.  In your linked example, the intent is to keep the example simple, not efficient

Comment: @MadProgrammer In my scenario the server will send continuously strings. So for now it  is a Server to client comm only. What do you think I should do ? Create 1 socket on the client and keep it alive? How do I keep it alive ?

Comment: @TrtTrt Yes, you should probably keep the client `Socket` open - otherwise you might miss some data.  Simply keep reading from the `Socket` in some kind of loop until the `Socket` is either closed by the server or you no longer need it